# Cant get jquery AJAX to work node js express

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, node.js, express

I've been trying to get ajax to work on node js.  Its the first time working with ajax so i have been trying to test it out useing the console to check that it works but every time i try i don't get a response on the console.

Here is my code.

```
<script>

function getMessage() {

    var data = $("#messageselect").val()

    $.ajax({
        url: "/message",
        type: "POST",
        data: JSON.stringify(data)
        dataType: 'json',
        success: function(data) {
            console.log(data);
        }
        error : function(err)
        console.log("error fetching message");
    });
}
</script>
```

server

```
app.post('/message', function(req, res) {

    console.log(JSON.stringify(req.body));


    Message.findOne({ 'page.message' : req.data }, function(err, message) {

        if(err)
            throw err;

        res.send(message);
    });
});
```

html

```
<form method="POST">
                        <select multiple="multiple" class="messageselect" onchange="getMessage()" id="messageselect">
                            <% if(message) { %>
                            <% for(i=messagecount-1;i>=0;i--) { %>
                            <option value="<%= message[i].page.message %>">From: <%= message[i].page.username %> Message: <%= message[i].page.messagetitle %></option>
                            <% } %>
                            <% } %>
                        </select><br><br><br>
                    </form>
```

Comment: If you are referring jquery locally make sure that express static middleware is enabled

Comment: The current code in the first block has a syntax error for the `error` callback.

Comment: Be more specific, what exactly isn't working?

Answer (score 3):

I guess this is *one of the* typos error in your code:

```
var = data $("#messageselect").val()
//--^^--------------------------------worng way to assign.
```

---

`jQuery.ajax()` needs an object to send:

```
var data = { data : $("#messageselect").val() };
```

and at the server you can use `req.body` to get the posted data:

```
 console.log(req.body.data);
```

**Note:**

For this you need to have `body-parser` for it, so make sure to include it in the code configs above.

Comment: There's actually more than one typo, as in missing comma and curlybraces. Also, the OP probably needs a bodyparser for that?

Comment: @adeneo absolutely. bodyParser is required and as i mentioned _one of a typo_ above.

Answer (score 0):

Could you please try `$http` like below format ,

```
$http.post(//url , //data )
   .success (function() {})
   .error(function() {});
```

Comment: @Sirko . sorry I couldnt read properly your comment . I accept it . It is not an angular specific code ..

Answer (score 0):

```
$.ajax({
    url: "/message",
    type: "POST",
    data: JSON.stringify(data)
    dataType: 'json',
    success: function(data) {
        console.log(data);
    }
    error : function(err)
    console.log("error fetching message");
});
```

They are missing braces at the error handler

```
error : function(err) {
        console.log("error fetching message");
}
```

Maybe not the right way so you also can try :

```
$.ajax({
    url: '/message',
    type: 'POST',
    dataType: 'JSON',
    data: {JSON.stringify(data)},
    success: function(data) {
        console.log(data);
    }
    error : function(err) {
        console.log("error fetching message");
    }
});
```

Have you ever tried using `curl` to POST something on server ?

Comment: Try using browser debug console to follow your code.

Answer (score 0):

In addition to existing answers you should also pass the proper `Content-Type` with your AJAX request:

```
$.ajax({
    url: "/message",
    type: "POST",
    data: JSON.stringify(data)
    dataType: 'json',
    contentType: 'application/json' //here it is
    //...
});
```